# maybeAuthId Type Error

Tags: haskell, yesod

I have a scaffolded site and I am using this snippet of code in the Home Handler.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TupleSections, OverloadedStrings #-}
module Handler.Home where

import Import
import Yesod.Auth

getHomeR :: Handler RepHtml   
getHomeR = do
  defaultLayout $ do
    maid <- maybeAuthId
    setTitle "Welcome!"
    $(widgetFile "homepage")
```

I would like to access  `maid`  in my homepage.hamlet file. However, I get the following error:

```
Handler/Home.hs:10:17:
    Couldn't match expected type `WidgetT site0 IO t0' 
                with actual type `HandlerT master0 IO (Maybe (AuthId master0))'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: maid <- maybeAuthId
    In the second argument of `($)', namely
      `do { maid <- maybeAuthId;
            setTitle "Welcome!";
            $(widgetFile "homepage") }'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block:
      defaultLayout
      $ do { maid <- maybeAuthId;
             setTitle "Welcome!";
             $(widgetFile "homepage") }
```

I get the above error message whether or not I put any contents inside homepage.hamlet. Instead of using   `$(widgetFile "homepage")`, if I paste the whamlet code snippet from the Yesod Book (Auth section), it works fine.

If I remove the call to maybeAuthId, the issue goes away too. I am guessing it is something to do with the call to maybeAuthId and using the widgetFile but I am not sure how to fix the issue. Any help appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`maybeAuthId` lives in the `Handler` monad, and the inside of `defaultLayout` is a `Widget`, which is why you have a mismatch. You could do one of the following:

- Convert the `Handler` action to a `Widget` action using [handlerToWidget](http://haddocks.fpcomplete.com/fp/7.4.2/20130622-109/yesod-core/Yesod-Core-Widget.html#v%3ahandlerToWidget)
- Move the `maybeAuthId` call to before `defaultLayout`

Comment: Thank you, Michael. It worked and thanks for the explanation as well.